# How to filter out a state array values based on elements located in another array in state?

Tags: reactjs, filter, state

I have state data that looks like this:

```
 state = {
      search: “”
      tagValue: “”
      data: [
           {  
              id: 1,
              fName: "Henry",
              lName: "Jones"
              email: “lol@hotmail.com”,
              gpa: “3.6”
              tag: [
                   "hello", "bye"
              ] 
           },
           {  
              fName: "Jeffrey",
              lName: "Johnston”,
              email: “hehdbejeu@gmail.com”,
              gpa: “2.6”,
              tag: [
                   "hello", "bye"
              ] 
           },
           {  
              fName: "Henry",
              lName: "Jones"
              gpa: “1.9”
              tag: [
              ] 
           }
      ]
  }
```

I've figured out how to filter the data array based on user input by doing:

```
 let studentListFilter = this.state.data.filter((student) => {
       return (
         student.firstName
           .toLowerCase()
           .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
         student.lastName
           .toLowerCase()
           .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
 }
```

and then returning studentListFilter in my render method. search is a state value updated based on user input. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to compare values located within an array, specifically tag in this case, to user input.

I've tried doing this to no avail:

```
let studentListFilter = this.state.data.filter((student) => {
      return (
        student.fName
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        student.lName
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        student.tag.map(
          (individualTag) =>
            individualTag
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.state.tagValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        )
      );
    });
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Please provide working example in https://codesandbox.io/ reproducing your issue for better understanding..

Comment: You are just wanting to check that `tagValue` is contained in at least one `student.tag` array?

Comment: I want to see if its atleast similar to one of the elements in the student.tag array

Comment: Can you update your question with the data you are filtering, and the objects you are filtering by. The answer below is on the right track but we need to see the structure of the filtering object(s).

Comment: I’ve updated the structure of the state data in the post. Each element in the data array is supposed to provide information about a studeny. I pretty much map through the data object in the array through studentListFilter and display individual divs for firstnamelastname, gpa, email. The user is able to input strings into the tag array for each student. And there are two text inputs, the first one allowing to filter the data array by first name or last name and the second one, which im having problems with, allows the user to filter based on tags for each student.

Comment: So if i input hello for the tag textinput only first two elements in the array should show since they have “hello” tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues is that when checking if any of the string values includes the filtering input is that all strings include the empty string.

```js
console.log("test".indexOf('') !== -1);
console.log("test".includes(''));
```

So the problem arises when you have two filtering inputs and assume when they apply to the data. Because the above then one of your conditions is always true if one of the inputs is empty and thus the data is never filtered.

1. Need to change assumption about empty filter strings, if they are empty then no filtering should occur, so only apply searches if filters strings are truthy, ie. non-empty strings.
2. First conditional test if **both** filters active, to break ties
3. Second test each condition individually
4. Return true to not filter data at all

Filter logic:

```
this.state.data
  .filter(student => {
    if (this.state.search && this.state.tagValue) {
      return (
        (student.fName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search) ||
          student.lName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search)) &&
        student.tag.some(tag => tag.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.tagValue))
      );
    }
    if (this.state.search) {
      return (
        student.fName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search) ||
        student.lName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search)
      );
    }
    if (this.state.tagValue) {
      return student.tag.some(tag =>
        tag.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.tagValue)
      );
    }
    return true;
  })
```

As can be seen there is a lot of repetition, a bit more DRY approach:

```
{this.state.data
  .filter(({ fName, lName, tag }) => {
    const includesName = [fName.toLowerCase(), lName.toLowerCase()].some(
      name => name.includes(this.state.search)
    );
    const includesTag = tag.some(tag =>
      tag.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.tagValue)
    );

    if (search && tagValue) {
      return includesName && includesTag;
    }
    if (search) {
      return includesName;
    }
    if (tagValue) {
      return includesTag;
    }
    return true;
  })
```

[image: Edit multi-property filter demo]

Answer (score 0):

basically you can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for your use case:

something like this:

```
    let studentListFilter = this.state.data.filter((student) => {
      const matchFirstName = student.fName
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

      const matchLastName = student.lName
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1

      // will return true if one of your tags match the search
      const someFnCB = (individualTag) => {
 return individualTag.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
};


      const matchTag = student.tag.some(someFnCB)


      return matchFirstName || matchLastName || matchTag;
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to see if the individualTag is atleast similar instead of having to match fully with the tagValue state property?

Comment: the `some` function will return true if any of the `individualTag` matches the search string.
so if you look for `aw` and you have the tags `awesome` `awful` `raw` `nothing` the first three tags will match

Comment: I'm getting an individualTag.toLowerCase() is not a function

Comment: I've added .toString() to individualTag so I don't get the error anymore but the state doesn't filter still